# Error from ReflectionClass:InvokeArgs

Tags: php, mysqli

I have the following code which was working until recently but is now giving an error. (I suspect my website host may have moved me to a new server or upgraded something without letting me know - again!)

```
function SqlPrepareAndExecute() {
 global $mysqli;
 // get the function parameters
 $args=func_get_args();
 // get the sql, and remove from the list
 $sql=array_shift($args);
 // prepare the statement
 if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)) {
  // need to do some clever reflection stuff to call bind_param
  $ref = new ReflectionClass('mysqli_stmt'); 
  $method = $ref->getMethod("bind_param"); 
  if($method->invokeArgs($stmt,$args))
   // execute the statement
   if ($stmt->execute())
    // it worked!
    return true;
   else 
    $Error="Failed to execute prepared query";
  else
   $Error="Failed to bind query parameters";
 }
 else
  $Error="Failed to prepare query";
 error_log("SqlPrepareAndExecute " . $Error . "\n");
 error_log("Error #" . $mysqli->errno . "\n" . $mysqli->error,0);
 return false;
}
```

called like this:

```
if (SqlPrepareAndExecute($sql,'ssssi',$_POST['  etc...
```

Error:

> PHP Warning:  Parameter 2 to mysqli_stmt::bind_param() expected to be a reference, value given in ...
>   PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Invocation of method mysqli_stmt::bind_param() failed' in ...

php version is 5.6.33

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: Why do you use reflection?

Comment: From the manual about [mysqli_stmt()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) _"Binds **variables** to a prepared statement as parameters"_ - What you are doing is trying to set a value, not a variable.

Comment: And if you still want to use reflection, then create an array of references to your variables from `$args`.

Comment: This is one (of multiple) situation where [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) would make your life much easier with it's [bindValue()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php),

Comment: I can't remember where I got this code from originally. It was some time ago. I can't remember now whether I got it as is from one source, or cobbled it together myself from separate examples on mysqli and passing multiple parameters.

Comment: I assume I used reflection because at the time I couldn't find another way to acheive binding a variable number of arguments as parameters

Comment: I managed to get it working by looping through the arguments and converting them all to references.
If there is a better (simpler) way to implement this function without using reflection though, please post it up as an answer. This function does seem unnecessarily over-complicated for a simple task of implementing a mysql database update.

Comment: Looks like I may have got the idea to use reflection from here:
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php#104073

Comment: found a solution using the new splat operator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

php 5.6 now has ... operator. So this can be simplified as follows:

```
function SqlPrepareAndExecute($sql, $types, ...$params) {
 global $mysqli;
 // prepare the statement
 if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql)) {
  // bind the parameters
  if ($stmt->bind_param($types, ...$params))
   // execute the statement
   if ($stmt->execute())
    // it worked!
    return true;
   else 
    $Error="Failed to execute prepared query";
  else
   $Error="Failed to bind query parameters";
 }
 else
  $Error="Failed to prepare query";
 error_log("SqlPrepareAndExecute " . $Error . "\n");
 error_log("Error #" . $mysqli->errno . "\n" . $mysqli->error,0);
 return false;
}
```